# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. Отсутствует доступ

Tags: python, файлы, файловая-система, urllib

Файл, который должен скачать, не может сохраниться в нужной директории:

```
def Download(self):
        print('Start Download')

        download_url = 'http://valheim.by/upload/Valheim.zip'
        save_location = 'D:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Valheim/ValheimByLauncher'

        if download_url == '' or save_location == '':
            print('Provide a valid URL or save location')
        else:

            urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url , save_location , self.Handel_Progress)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\Stepan\Desktop\WoVBOT\Launcher.py", line 133, in Download
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url , save_location , self.Handel_Progress)
          File "C:\Users\Stepan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 249, in urlretrieve
        tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Valheim/ValheimByLauncher'
    Программа "python.exe" завершилась с кодом -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Пробовал сделать тестовый код с requests:

```
from clint.textui import progress
import requests
import os 

r = requests.get('http://valheim.by/upload/Valheim.zip', stream=True)
path = 'D:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Valheim/ValheimByLauncher'
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
    for chunk in progress.bar(r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), expected_size=(total_length/1024) + 1): 
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
```

---

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Valheim/ValheimByLauncher'
Трассировка стека:
 >  File "C:\Users\Stepan\Desktop\WoVBOT\модуль1.py", line 7, in <module> (Current frame)
 >    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
```

Comment: Ну нет прав доступа, такое бывает. Может туда только пользователь с админскими правами может писать в этот каталог.

Comment: @CrazyElf, я ни куда не могу зайти. Какую бы директорию я не указал.

Comment: @hoojpop Вы прямо директорию что-ли открываете на запись?

Comment: @GrAnd, да. То есть созданная за ранее директория (папка). И туда должен скачаться архив с ссылки.

Comment: Так может всё-таки создавать (открывать на запись) файл в этой директириии писать в него?

Comment: @GrAnd, За ранее создать там архив?

Comment: Открывать на запись надо файл. Вы же в него его содержимое писать собрались. Т.е. добавляете к строке с вашей целевой директорией имя файла (см. [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) если надо динамически) - получается строка с полным путём до файла. Открываете этот файл на запись и пишите в него.